# How to make a POST request to a nodejs RESTful API in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, reactjs, api

I had my backend restful API built with `nodejs` and `express`, I also have a front-end built on Reactjs, I am trying to make a login page.
My idea is making a POST request in `Reactjs` to my `Nodejs` restful API, including username and password, then the back end will check if the request information correct will return a token, else will return a fail message.
But I don't know which is the proper way to make a POST request in `reactjs`.
Do i just using `$.ajax()`?
I am trying to avoid using `jquery` because I think there are many ways to do the same stuff.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use `axios` or `fetch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fetch` if you don't want to go for third party libraries.

Check [here](https://blog.hellojs.org/fetching-api-data-with-react-js-460fe8bbf8f2) a nice article about how to use **fetch** in react.

Comment: Thanks, this absolutely made my day.

Answer (score 2):

Use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). There's no need to use `jquery`.

```
axios.post("http://api/login", { options }).then(res => ...).catch(err => ...)
```

options will be: `{ username: username, password: password ...etc }`

What I like about it over `fetch` is that you can define a [baseurl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axioscreateconfig) (instead of writing `http://localhost:5000/api/...` over and over for each `AJAX` request) and `axios` automatically handles `JSON`.

Comment: shouldn't it be axios.post("http://APIURL", {username: username, password: password}).then(res => ...).catch(err => ...) ?? THE SECOND ARGUMENT

Comment: Updated the comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use axios.js with saga.js frameworks.

```js
// Send a POST request
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply achieve this

```
function submitRequest(opts) {
      console.log('Posting request to your API...');
      fetch('http://your_url', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(opts)
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
       console.log(':', data);
      });
    }
```